# How to add a middleware for user permission plug-in for strapi?

Tags: authentication, strapi, user-permissions

I am trying to add a middleware or policy to the user permission plugin in strapi but unfortunately it is not calling the plug in

```js
{
  method: "GET",
  path: '/users',
  handler: 'user.find',
  config: {
    middlewares: [
      (ctx, next) => {
        console.log('not working')
        return next();
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

adding a middleware to api `/users` in `user-permission-details`
in `strapi` but it is not working

The middleware in is defined by

The problem is that the middleware is not getting called and as a result it is not defined in the module.exports function above.

Answer (score 2):

I found that you can add policies, middlewares or even modify core functionality of the plugin by creating a file:

> src/extensions/{pluggin}/strapi-server.js

In this case, if you want to modify the users-permissions plugin it would be:

> src/extensions/users-permissions/strapi-server.js

Starting with the basic export:

```
("use strict");

module.exports = (plugin) => {
  return plugin;
};
```

You can start modifying the plugin functionality. For example, if you want to add a middleware to an specific route, you could create a global middleware and the add it to the route:

```
("use strict");

module.exports = (plugin) => {
  plugin.routes["content-api"].routes = plugin.routes["content-api"].routes.map(
    (item) => {
      if (item.method == "GET" && item.path == "/users") {
        item.config.policies = [
          "global::middleware-name",
        ];
      }

      return item;
    }
  );
  return plugin;
};
```

I hope that this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, but if I try console logging inside `module.exports = (plugin) => {` nothing happens ? I've put the file in src/extensions/users-permissions/strapi-server.js